# simple TCP server-client using two Android emulators

Tags: android, tcp, client

can someone please suggest me a simple demo app with code for understanding the setup of a TCP server-client configuration using android emulators? I don't have much understanding of Java socket programming but I know C socket programming quite well. 
 thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of information how to create a simple server-client connection. For instance, [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) article. In [this](http://www.roman10.net/android-tcp-client-and-server-communication-programmingillustrated-with-example/) post you can find a link to a demo app.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://learneasyandroid.blogspot.in/2013/06/tcp-communication-in-android-example.html) may Help you

Underlying Algorithm:
Basic description of algorithm in step by step form:

1. Create Two Projects one for server MyServer and another for client
   ServerClient.
2. Put the following code snippet in res folder of
   MyServer project

res/layout/main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
/>
  <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TextView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

3.) Put the following code snippet in res folder of ServerClient project res/layout/main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
 />
 <EditText android:text="EditText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </EditText>
 <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/myButton"  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </Button>
 </LinearLayout>
```

4.) Add the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml of both project :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
```

5.) Redirect the port :
i) run -> cmd -> telnet localhost 5554
ii) redir add tcp:5000:6000
6.) Run the both applications.

MyServer class will look like following:
     package com.app.MyServer;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MyServer extends Activity {
   ServerSocket ss = null;
   String mClientMsg = "";
   Thread myCommsThread = null;
   protected static final int MSG_ID = 0x1337;
   public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

   @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
   tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");
   this.myCommsThread = new Thread(new CommsThread());
   this.myCommsThread.start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   try {
        // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
       ss.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       switch (msg.what) {
       case MSG_ID:
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            tv.setText(mClientMsg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
  };
   class CommsThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       Socket s = null;
        try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        Message m = new Message();
        m.what = MSG_ID;
        try {
            if (s == null)
                s = ss.accept();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String st = null;
            st = input.readLine();
            mClientMsg = st;
            myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

ServerClient class will look like following:

```
package com.app.ServerClient;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

public class SocketClient extends Activity {
   private Button bt;
   private TextView tv;
   private Socket socket;
   private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.2.2";
   // AND THAT'S MY DEV'T MACHINE WHERE PACKETS TO
   // PORT 5000 GET REDIRECTED TO THE SERVER EMULATOR'S
   // PORT 6000
   private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 5000;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
      tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
      try {
         InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
         socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
      } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
          }
      bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
               EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
               String str = et.getText().toString();
               PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new 

OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
               out.println(str);
               Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
               tv.setText("Error1");
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               tv.setText("Error2");
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               tv.setText("Error3");
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```